# Creating a simple animation in React-Pose

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-hooks

I'm having trouble creating a simple animation in React-Pose. The two problems are

1) I can't get the animation to revert to the initial condition. The hovering variable is changing to false when the mouse leaves, but it the animation doesn't change back.

2) I can't manipulate the animation, I wanted to have a longer duration and maybe an ease out or something, but its just an instant snap to the hovered status.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import posed from 'react-pose';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const UpFor = () => {

const [hovering, setHovering] = useState(false);

const HoverContainer = posed.div({
    hoverable: true
})

const Container = styled(HoverContainer)`
font-family: 'Baumans';
font-size: 220px;
display: flex;
cursor: pointer;
`

const Up = styled.div`
color: #81D6E3;`

const Four = styled.div`
color: #FF101F
`
const Fours = styled.div`
display: flex;
`
const MirroredFour = posed.div({
unhovered: {transform: 'rotatey(0deg)'},
hovered: {transform: 'rotateY(180deg)',
        transition: {
            type: 'tween',
            duration: '2s'
        }}
})

const SecondFour = styled(MirroredFour)`
color: #FF101F
position: absolute;
transform-origin: 67%;
`


return (
    <Container onMouseEnter={() => {setHovering({ hovering: true }), console.log(hovering)}}
               onMouseLeave={() => {setHovering({ hovering: false }), console.log(hovering)}}>
         <Up>Up</Up><Fours><Four>4</Four>
                <SecondFour pose={hovering ? "hovered" : "unhovered"}
                >4</SecondFour></Fours>
    </Container>)
}

export default UpFor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two main issues with your code:

1. `duration` does not appear to support string values like '2s'. I changed this to `2000`.
2. You were defining your components (e.g. using `styled.div`, `posed.div`) inside of your render function. This caused these components to be treated by React as unique component types with each re-render. This results in those components being unmounted and re-mounted each render which prevents transitions from working since the element isn't changing -- instead it is being replaced by a new component of a different type.

Below is a working version of your code which moves the component definitions outside of the render (`UpFor`) function. You can play around with it in the sandbox provided.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import posed from "react-pose";

const Container = styled.div`
  font-family: "Baumans";
  font-size: 220px;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

const Up = styled.div`
  color: #81d6e3;
`;

const Four = styled.div`
  color: #ff101f;
`;
const Fours = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;
const MirroredFour = posed.div({
  unhovered: { transform: "rotateY(0deg)" },
  hovered: {
    transform: "rotateY(180deg)",
    transition: {
      type: "tween",
      duration: 2000
    }
  }
});

const SecondFour = styled(MirroredFour)`
color: #FF101F
position: absolute;
transform-origin: 67%;
`;

const UpFor = () => {
  const [hovering, setHovering] = useState(false);

  console.log("hovering", hovering);
  return (
    <Container
      onMouseEnter={() => {
        setHovering(true);
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        setHovering(false);
      }}
    >
      <Up>Up</Up>
      <Fours>
        <Four>4</Four>
        <SecondFour pose={hovering ? "hovered" : "unhovered"}>4</SecondFour>
      </Fours>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default UpFor;
```

[image: Edit Pose]

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent a great deal of effort trying to figure it out! :D